# When Will PHP's `*_pconnect` Spawn New Connections

Tags: php, database, oracle

Most of the native, non-PDO database drivers for PHP include two different connection functions.  One for opening a connection, a second for opening a persistent connection.  For example, the Oracle/OCI function library has both an [`oci_connect`](http://php.net/oci_connect) and an [`oci_pconnect`](http://php.net/oci_pconnect) function.

The PHP manual has the [following warning about persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php).

> Note, however, that this can have some drawbacks if you are using a database with connection limits that are exceeded by persistent child connections. If your database has a limit of 16 simultaneous connections, and in the course of a busy server session, 17 child threads attempt to connect, one will not be able to.

While this is pretty straightforward, what's less clear is **when** PHP will open a new connection.  That is, the ideal behind a persistent connection is "the first request opens a connection, future requests use that same connection".  However, the above warning makes it sounds like there's also cases where PHP will know a certain persistent connection is saturated, and open a second connection.

**How** does PHP know when to do this? What are the rules for when it will happen? Is it `mod_php`/FastCGI depending?  Apache threading model dependent? Neither? Both?  etc.  Asking specifically for the Oracle/OCI driver, but curious about how the entire system works.

Comment: IIRC it's within the context of a single script execution. So you can be lazy and call `*_pconnect` all over the place instead of passing around connection resources like a rational person. *It does not cross the boundaries between PHP executions.* As for how PHP knows when a connection is busy, I'd imagine that that's built into the driver.

Comment: @Sammitch That's wrong -- per the documentation of oci_pconnect "a typical PHP application will have a single persistent connection open against an Oracle server per Apache child process (or PHP FastCGI/CGI process)

Comment: Cool beans. So how many simultaneous PHP executions can happen inside an apache/CGI/fCGI worker? Because it's *one*.

Comment: @Sammitch lots of confusing/unclear terminology here in PHP land -- when you said PHP executions I thought you meant web requests, not individual worker executions (my mistake)  Appreciate the correction.